# SQL Select 1 line in function of 3 MAX/MIN fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to create a view, or just a select for the moment, based on this function :

```
SELECT
  FLAG
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TE.FLAG
  FROM
    EVT E
    INNER JOIN EVT_TYP TE ON TE.ID = E.FK_TYPE_EVT
  WHERE
    E.FK_OBJECT = NUMOBJECT
  order by
    trunc(E.EVT_DATE) desc,
    e.evt_number desc,
    e.id desc
)
where
  rownum = 1;
```

NUMOBJECT is the function parameter. Function returns one FLAG for that NUMOBJECT.
I want to select one flag for each E.FK_OBJECT IN EVT table.

Problems are I can have several lines in EVT table for one E.FK_OBJECT the same day, and I don't have time part of the date, most of the time. E.evt_number can be int or NULL. And E.id haven't the same order that E.EVT_DATE.

I don't know how I can succeed it, can you help me please? I try with imbricates select but looks likes it's not possible beacause of NULL e.evt_number.

I work on Oracle DB.

edit :
Sample of data : 
[Heberger image http://img15.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_229922Sanstitre.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=229922Sanstitre.png)

I tried this :

```
SELECT E.Fk_Object
    ,TE.FLAG
FROM (
    SELECT
        E.Fk_Object
        ,E.EVT_DATE
        ,E.evt_number
        ,MAX(E.id) id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            E.Fk_Object
            ,E.EVT_DATE
            ,MAX(NVL(e.evt_number, - 1)) evt_number
        FROM (
            SELECT
                E.Fk_Object
                ,MAX(E.EVT_DATE) EVT_DATE
            FROM EVT E
            GROUP BY E.Fk_Object
            ) E_MAX
        INNER JOIN EVT E ON E.Fk_Object = E_MAX.Fk_Object
            AND E.EVT_DATE = E_MAX.EVT_DATE
        WHERE e.flg_suppression = 0
            AND e.evt_date IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY E.Fk_Object
            ,E.EVT_DATE
        ) E_MAX_2
    INNER JOIN EVT E ON E.Fk_Object = E_MAX_2.Fk_Object
        AND E.EVT_DATE = E_MAX_2.EVT_DATE
        AND NVL(e.evt_number, - 1) = NVL(E_MAX_2.evt_number, - 1)
    GROUP BY E.Fk_Object
        ,E.EVT_DATE
        ,E.evt_number
    ) E_MAX_3
left JOIN EVT E ON E.Fk_Object = E_MAX_3.Fk_Object
    AND E.EVT_DATE = E_MAX_3.EVT_DATE
    AND NVL(e.evt_number, - 1) = NVL(E_MAX_3.evt_number, - 1)
    AND E.id = E_MAX_3.id
INNER JOIN EVT_TYP TE ON TE.id = E.FK_EVT_TYP
ORDER BY 2
    ,3;
```

But it doesn't give me same results than function

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. Why `NUMOBJECT` doesnt have parameter?

Comment: Here is a sample : http://hpics.li/9bb51cf NUMOBJECT is the name of the parameter, its value is a number like 150146, like in the screenshoot

Comment: Your first query (not function) selects the latest record for a given object and returns the flag of this record. How is this different from what you actually want?

Comment: Because calling this function for a list of objects is too slaw, I need to optimize this

Answer (score 0):

Done !

Instead of NVL(E_MAX_2.evt_number, - 1) I have to use NVL(E_MAX_2.evt_number, 99) and not forget the trunc() for E.EVT_DATE to keep the same order than the function and it is ok !!
With that, it runs in 12 seconds. It was 54 before with the function.
I will test to create a view to see if it's even better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a query that gives you the latest flag for not only one, but several objects. You can do this by selecting records for all these objects and then grouping by object applying Oracle's `KEEP FIRST/LAST`.

```
select 
  e.fk_object,
  max(te.flag) keep (dense_rank first 
    order by trunc(e.evt_date) desc, e.evt_number desc, e.id desc) as current_flag
from evt e
join evt_typ et on et.id = e.fk_type_evt
where fk_object in (numobject1, numobject2, numobject3)
group by e.fk_object;
```

The same can be used as a subquery. Let's say you have a table `OBJECTS` with a column `STATUS` and you want to show all objects of status 'new' with their current flag each:

```
select o.*, flags.current_flag
from objects o
join
(
  select 
    e.fk_object,
    max(te.flag) keep (dense_rank first
      order by trunc(e.evt_date) desc, e.evt_number desc, e.id desc) as current_flag
  from evt e
  join evt_typ et on et.id = e.fk_type_evt
  group by e.fk_object
) flags on flags.fk_object = o.id
where o.status = 'new';
```